# Isolated UART communication: Which side should send the supply for the isolator?

Tags: power-supply, uart, isolation

[image: System Block Diagram]

I am in a situation to establish an isolated UART communication between two separate PCBs. The first PCB regulates and sends the required isolated power of the second one. The UART communication will be referenced to this isolated supply of the second PCB. There is an isolator IC on the first PCB. I will be using [Si8621](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si86xx.pdf) if it matters.

Now the question is, how do I send the supply voltages of the isolator IC?

Solution 1:
Since the isolated supply is generated on the first PCB, I can directly feed the IC from the first PCB. This way, I only need to send the RX and TX lines on the communication connector.
Pros: A 2-pin connector will suffice.
Cons: Isolated voltage traces will dangerously travel across the PCB.

Solution 2:
I use a 4-pin connector and transfer the required power to the isolator.
Pros: Is there benefit in doing this?
Cons: I use a larger connector. I create a loop back of the isolated supply.

I am confused and I can't choose between these two solutions. Is there any rule of thumb for a situation like this? Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: This isn't something that has a definitive answer, especially once you source the power for one system from the other.  Note that a lot of real-world isolated systems use current mode signaling with an optoisolator, for example MIDI.

Comment: Are you using a separate connector/cable for the power? Why can't you combine it with the communication one? And why is the on-the-PCB travel dangerous?

Comment: You probably need a "ground"/reference wire along with the TX and RX lines.

Comment: I think that [ISO7041](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7041.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1681621498157&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fiso7041) from TI. Low-power GPIO, UART and SPI will help to isolated the UART, but not sure about the isolated power.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be running your UART on 3.3V levels from board 1 to board 2 we have to assume they are not far away from each other. That means it should not matter that much where you place your supplies.

There are other issues that will need your attention, namely:

-You actually need two power supplies for the Si86xx family. Refer to [Si86XX CMOS DIGITAL ISOLATOR-BASED SERIALINTERFACE USER'S GUIDE](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/user-guides/Si86xxCOM-EVB_UG.pdf).

-As Peter says in his comment [above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447512/isolated-uart-communication-which-side-should-send-the-supply-for-the-isolator#comment1123007_447512), there is a good chance you need an additional GND cable. You need a return path for the current running on TX and RX. With a non-isolated UART, oftentimes you would not need this return path because all equipment is connected to the same safety earth. But I'm sure you have experienced this problem yourself if you ever tried to make two handheld battery-powered devices talk to each other.

Just in case you want to take a look, I'm including a bunch of references I find useful:

-[RS485 in practice](http://support.fccps.cz/download/adv/frr/RS485/RS485.html)

-[TI Digital Isolator Design Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla284b/slla284b.pdf)

-[Using DIGI products in the real world](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90000641.pdf)

-[Analog Dialogue: Digital Isolators](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/digital-isolators-protect-rs232-bus.html)

-[Serial Port Complete](http://janaxelson.com/spc.htm) by Jan Axelson