# ADM2483 or MAX485 Design: Modbus RS485 RTU bus in harsh environment

Tags: schematics, rs485

I'm currently out of ideas, i have a simple Wigoneer RS485 TTL interface ([Sch link here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/411PTilsAQL._AC_SX425_.jpg)) with MAX485 wired to my ESP32 based board, in my lab everything works like a charm with 1300 meters of CAT6 UTP Cable, but when i try to put in production with 800 meters of CAT6/FTP cable nothing works (using ModbusMaster library i get 224 error)

**keep in mind that the cable it's placed in a cable duct with three phase lines, so it's a totally different condition instead my lab and it's placed in a harsh environment with motors, solder machines and so on...**

Anyway, i've decided to redesign my RS485 breakout board using an isolated transciever, in this case the ADM2483: it's a good idea? maybe can help me to solve this problems that i'm encountering in harsh environments?

This is the schematic reference that i'm planning to use:

VDD1: 3.3V - VDD2: 5V

[image: ADM2483_schematic]

Comment: Do the devices share a common ground reference wire?

Comment: If you mean the Tranciever and the field PLC no, they only have two wires (A-B), i've tried a simple USB-RS485WE interface to test the field PLC in order to understand what was going wrong and nothing works, when i've switched to this interface (isolated: https://qeed.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/MI000180_Q-USB-ITA_ENG.pdf) magically everything started working...why???

Comment: Is your CAT6 shielded? Or is it just basic spool stuff you buy at hardware stores?

Comment: It's a Commscope shielded cable certified CAT6A with external foil shield and additional pairs shield

Comment: Really, no common ground reference wire? Is the ESP32 grounded? Does it have grounded power supply, or floating? Is the device at the other end of the 800m cable also grounded, or is it floating?

Comment: The ESP32 Is the olimex ESP32 Poe, at the other end there are only wired the A and B cables

Comment: Yes, but that does not answer the question whether both devices have ground reference via some path, like mains earth. If you don't know, you should not expect it to work with only two wires either.

Comment: It's not so simple to answer your question, but I'll try to go...The two devices does not have the common ground reference in the bus cable, but they are respectively powered with as following: ESP32 Poe, the supply comes from a Cisco Poe switch with power cord ground connected, the PLC (Eaton) has a 230Vac power with ground reference.

Answer (score 1):

So as one device (PLC) has reference to mains earth, and the other device is floating (PoE by definition is isolated), they have no common ground reference, so simply two data wires of RS-485 will not work and can even break RS-485 tranceivers with large potential differences between the devices.

Standard RS-485 tranceivers such as the MAX485 allow up to 7V difference between their grounds, so this will be exceeded if the PoE device is floating. The isolated tranceiver works because it allows the isolated side ground reference to float and be set via the data wires, and it will allow higher difference between isolated ground and PC ground. Although that is not even necessary, because the PC is also most likely earthed, so there will be a common ground reference between PLC and PC, via mains earthing.

Basically, since the ESP32 is powered via PoE, you need the reference ground wire between ESP32 and PLC.

Comment: "Basically, since the ESP32 is powered via PoE, you need the reference ground wire between ESP32 and PLC." This assumption it's valid only for not ISO transceivers, right?

Comment: "The isolated tranceiver works because it allows the isolated side ground reference to float and be set via the data wires, and it will allow higher difference between isolated ground and PC ground." How this is possible? This concept isn't very clear for me, you can do more in depth explanation? Many, many thanks man! :)

Comment: The assumption is valid for all tranceivers, isolated or not. The tranceiver has to have a reference potential with the other tranceiver that is within 7 volts. The isolated tranceiver isolates, so for example, there can be hundreds of volts between PC ground side and isolated tranceiver ground. The isolated ground must be connected to the remote traceiver ground, so that tranceivers have grounds within 7V.

Comment: And why using a USB rs485 isolated tranceiver everything works? I mean, my notebook is not sharing the same ground and in addition it's on battery... This is not definitely clear to me, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Good point, I assumed a grounded desktop PC. However, the laptop potential, grounded or not, makes no difference, because the RS-485 tranceiver isolates the computer from the bus. In either case, the isolated side common mode potential is set by data wires.

Comment: So, if I've understood right, in this case (without a common ground reference) the isolated DC DC transformer on the tranceiver will allow the common ground potential set from the two data wires, without needs of common ground wire, right?

Comment: This is a very old and nuanced debate. The answer you have here is quite right. If you want to get to a deeper understanding you can read through [this](http://support.fccps.cz/download/adv/frr/RS485/RS485.html) and if you have the equipment and patience you might want to use your scope and see what's going on each case. Not every IC and circuit has the same tolerance to noise. I posted other useful links [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447512/isolated-uart-communication-which-side-should-send-the-supply-for-the-isolator/448278#448278)

Comment: Its bad juju to run comms next to three phase. Just don’t do it. You don’t want to make a transformer. You also need your 0V wire for the transzorbs to work